# Is there a way to search for ArgumentCountError in PHP?

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7, php-5.3, migrating

Is there a way to search for *ArgumentCountErrors* (to few arguments passed into a function from a function call) in a project?

I had no luck with PhpStorm, it only displays an error if there are too many passed arguments.

We are migrating to PHP 7 and the size of the project makes it impossible to find all of them, searching manually before going live.